# R data.table merge two columns from the same table

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have:

```
inputDT <- data.table(COL1 = c(1, NA, NA), COL1 = c(NA, 2, NA), COL1 = c(NA, NA, 3))
inputDT
   COL1 COL1 COL1
1:    1   NA   NA
2:   NA    2   NA
3:   NA   NA    3
```

I want

```
outputDT <- data.table(COL1 = c(1,2,3))
outputDT
   COL1
1:    1
2:    2
3:    3
```

Essentially, I have a data.table with multiple columns whose names are the same (values are mutually exclusive), and I need to generate just one column to combine those.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R: coalescing a large data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851873/r-coalescing-a-large-data-frame) ; You should find a solution there, except if you want to avoid calling `dplyr`; you can otherwise also call it within `DT`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP is asking for a `data.table` solution. As of version v1.12.4 (03 Oct 2019), the `fcoalesce()` function is available:

```
library(data.table)
inputDT[, .(COL1 = fcoalesce(.SD))]
```

> ```
>    COL1
> 1:    1
> 2:    2
> 3:    3
> ```

Comment: Some of my columns have text fields, and this approach works.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (less elegant than @Uwe's answer), if you have only numbers and `NA`, you can calculate the max of each row while removing NA:

```r
library(data.table)
inputDT[, .(COL2 = do.call(pmax, c(na.rm=TRUE, .SD)))]

  COL2
1:    1
2:    2
3:    3
```

Comment: Thanks ! I try but when I called back `inputDT` I get the former data.table.

Comment: An alternative to `do.call()` is `reduce()`: `inputDT[, .(COL2 = purrr::reduce(.SD, pmax, na.rm = TRUE))]`. `purrr::reduce()` is like base R's `Reduce()` but has the advantage that you can pass additional arguments to the function without having to write an anonymous function.

Comment: @Uwe, thanks for the tip. I don't know much about `purr` package, trying to learn it (slowly).

Comment: @Uwe the current solution *is* passing additional arguments to pmax() without having to write an anonymous function.

Comment: @sindri_baldur, Yes, indeed. My comment concerning passing additional arguments does _not_ refer to dc37's answer but refers solely to my suggestion of an alternative approach to use `purrr::reduce()` instead of `do.call()`. I was discussing the advantages of `purrr::reduce()` vs. `Reduce()`.